# Empathy missing it's theme?

Tags: 12.10, empathy

Here you can see that it is really ugly :

[image: image 1]

while my theme is:

[image: image 2]

I am on a fress install of Ubuntu 12.10.

P.s I am contacting with a facebook friend..

Comment: And now everything is ok.. Well that's weird..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also had the theme issue once. Just change the theme to something different and then change it back to ubuntu and you're fine.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, this didn't work for me. Interestingly, the styles aren't broken in the Theme selection window.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found to fix this was to actually invoke empathy from the command line with

```
empathy --show-preferences
```

and change the theme to what you want and then click close.

I cannot figure out why there is no menu displayed in empathy right now it's like they down-graded the display completely -- so frustrating

Hope that helps!